# When mocking an object, use spy or when?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I want to test a method, which gets an object with information as a parameter:

```
//mocking a user object with some random data
User user createMockUser(loginName, firstName, lastName, salutation, company, mailAddress);
//do something with that user object 
foo(user);
```

and the focus on the test is to test foo(user).

With these variants for createMockUser():

Using when functions:

```
protected User createMockUser(String loginName, String firstName, 
        String lastName, String salutation, String mailAddress) 
{
    User user = Mockito.mock(User.class);

    Mockito.when(user.getLoginName()).thenReturn(id);
    Mockito.when(user.getFirstName()).thenReturn(firstName);
    Mockito.when(user.getLastName()).thenReturn(lastName);
    Mockito.when(user.getSalutation()).thenReturn(salutation);
    Mockito.when(user.getMailAddress()).thenReturn(mailAddress);        
    return user;
}
```

using spy:

```
protected User createMockUser(String loginName, String firstName, 
        String lastName, String salutation, String mailAddress) 
{

    User spyUser = spy(new User());
    spyUser.setLoginName(loginName);
    spyUser.setFirstName(firstName); 
    spyUser.setLastName(lastName); 
    spyUser.setSalutation(salutation); 
    Mockito.when(spyUser.getMailAddress()).thenReturn(mailAddress); 

    return spyUser;
}
```

and this wouldn't work at all:

```
protected User createMockUser(String loginName, String firstName, 
        String lastName, String salutation, String mailAddress) 
{
    User user;
    user = Mockito.mock(User.class);
    user.setLoginName(loginName);
    user.setFirstName(firstName);
    user.setLastName(lastName);
    user.setSalutation(salutation);
    Mockito.when(user.getMailAddress()).thenReturn(mailAddress);        
    return user;
}
```

I am still new to mockito, but from what I get, spy really uses the object's methods to have the values in the object and when just makes the get function call to return what is indicated in the mock. But for this test, they do basically the same result-wise, since I only want to test foo. 
So, which one would be better or is there an even more elegant way?

Comment: Yes, there is a more "elegant" way: `User user = new User(); user.setLoginName(loginName); ...and so on, using other setters`. Mocking a class which only holds data and only exposes trivial getters/setters is a serious abuse of any mocking API. This is not the kind of thing they are intended for. Objects should be mocked for their interesting *behavior*, not for the *data* they may hold.

Comment: I would upvote Rogério's comment 100 times if I could. There is nothing interesting or useful obtained from mocking (or even unit testing!) a class that only has getters / setters. There are usually much more complex areas that would benefit from the effort within a given project.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking simple beans is usually not interesting. It returns anyway the value you have set with the setter method if you call the getter. No big deal.

On the other hand spying on simple beans makes sense, if you want to check how many times and with which parameters were the setters or getters called. So for verification spying is absolutely ok, and makes sense.